# Traversing an overflowing binary tree

Tags: binary-tree

Given a very large binary tree (i.e. with millions of nodes), how to handle determining the number of nodes in the tree? In other words, given the root node of this tree to a function, the function should return the number of nodes in the tree.

Or let's say how do you check if the Binary Tree is BST if the tree has very large number of nodes?

Comment: Assuming you don't want to simply count all nodes, what are your restrictions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Walk all nodes and check whatever conditions/metric you need. There is nothing else you can do without additional knowledge about the tree.

You can enforce particular conditions at the time when tree is created (i.e. must be balanced/sorted/whatever) or collect information about tree at creation time (i.e. store and constantly update number of children).

Answer (score 0):

To check if it's a VALID bst you have to visit every node depth first and ensure each node is smaller than the previous.

If you want to evaluate how long that will take for a balanced BST you could get a quick approximation of the size by counting the length of one leg, I believe the total size will be between 2^(n-1) and 2^n-1 inclusive